# OpenPop.NET - modifies a character in email

Tags: c#, vb.net, pop3, openpop

I'm using the OpenPop library to read emails. I have the problem that when reading the body of the Email, the library modifies a character.
See the following example:


Email body:

> DiseÃƒÂ±o

Code c#:

```c
OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client objPOP3 = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
OpenPop.Mime.Message message = default(OpenPop.Mime.Message);
OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart plainTextPart = default(OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart);
string bodyMailTxt = "";

objPOP3.Connect(Host, Port, UseSSL);
objPOP3.Authenticate(User, Password);

message = objPOP3.GetMessage(1);
plainTextPart = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion();
bodyMailTxt = plainTextPart.GetBodyAsText();
```

Code vb:

```vb
Dim objPOP3 As New OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client
Dim message As OpenPop.Mime.Message
Dim plainTextPart As OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart
Dim bodyMailTxt As String = ""

ObjPOP3.Connect(Host, Port, UseSSL)
ObjPOP3.Authenticate(User, Password)

message = objPOP3.GetMessage(1)
plainTextPart = message.FindFirstPlainTextVersion()
bodyMailTxt = plainTextPart.GetBodyAsText()
```

`bodyMailTxt` value is "DiseÃfÂ±o", which replaced the **ƒ** (latin small letter F whit hook) for **f** (latin small letter F).

I'd have to do to make this not happen?

Comment: Could you post the entire message (IE, the source code for the email) on a service such as pastebin? You could also try to mail the support mailing list hpop-users@lists.sourceforge.net

Comment: what you mean with the source code of the email? The body of the email only has the word "DiseÃƒÂ±o".

Comment: But what about the headers? For example subject, encoding, content type and so on. Like you only view the visual parts of a homepage, there is source code behind it (the HTML). The same applies to an email. An [introduction](http://hpop.sourceforge.net/emailIntroduction.php) is available at the OpenPop homepage.

Comment: Link in pastebin of what you requested: [test mail](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=HuCAiPbv)

Comment: Using [quoted-printable decoder](http://www.motobit.com/util/quoted-printable-decoder.asp) to decode "Dise=C3f=C2=B1o=20" in character set "iso-8859-1" gives "DiseÃfÂ¹o". The "f" character is not encoded in the source, so OpenPop cannot give any other answer than "f". Does other email clients show your latin "ƒ"?

Comment: But because it appears in the HTML "Dise=C3=83=C2=B1o", which when decoded gives "DiseÃƒÂ¹o"

Comment: That is true. Did not notice that. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) ƒ is not defined for iso-8859-1. Either way, it seems that OpenPop just decodes the source that it was given. Maybe something went wrong in the encoder?

Comment: This means that no solution?

Comment: I'm sorry but yes. The email does not contain the characters DiseÃfÂ±o. It is erroneously encoded. Can you see the correct characters with some other email client?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source for the `OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart` class, it looks like `plainTextPart.GetBodyAsText()`, is getting the text like this,  `return BodyEncoding.GetString(Body)`, where `BodyEncoding` is a public property of type `Encoding` and `Body` is a public property of the raw byte array that comprises the message.

I don't know and I can't really test, but it could be that the default encoding the message is using to decode the text isn't the same as what was used to send the text. You may be able to see what results you get by trying `plainTextPart.Encoding = Encoding.ASCII`, or  `plainTextPart.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8`, or `plainTextPart.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode` before calling the `.GetBodyAsText()` method.

Link to MessagePart source file:

http://hpop.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/hpop/trunk/OpenPop/Mime/MessagePart.cs?revision=377&view=markup

Comment: methods and properties that set the character code are private.